# Error in Python when using VPython

Tags: python, numpy, vpython

I am getting an error when I try to import anything or try to modify numpy statement to import anything other than **from numpy import arange** like  **from numpy import ***, or add any other import statements.

I also can't make my radius random floats it says r = random.uniform(0,2) AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'uniform'.

**This is the error I get when I try to modify the import statements:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 13, in <module>
    rate(5)
TypeError: rate() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'pmt', 'pv', and 'fv'
```

**Code:**

```
from visual import *
from math import cos,sin,pi

from numpy import arange


from random import *

s = sphere(pos=[1,0,0],radius=0.1,color = color.red)
s0 = sphere(pos=[0,0,0],radius=0.25,color = color.green)

for i in arange(0,100,0.1):
    rate(5)
    theta = randint(0,30)
    r = randint(-2,2)
    x = cos(theta)
    y = sin(theta)
    s.pos = [x,y,r]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to use `from <some_library> import *` in scripts or programs, because that imports *everything* from `<some_library>` into the current namespace.  If any of the names in `<some_library>` already exist in the current namespace, they will be redefined.  It is better to do, for example, either

```
import numpy as np
```

and use the prefix `np` to access the `numpy` namespace (e.g. `np.arange`), or explicitly import only exactly what you need in your script.  For example, to import `randint` from `random`,

```
from random import randint
```

In your case, both `numpy` and `visual` define a function called `rate`.  (See http://vpython.org/contents/docs/rate.html and http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rate.html.)  Apparently you had done `from numpy import *` when you got the error that you reported, so your script was calling `numpy.rate` and not `visual.rate`.

Comment: This fixed it thanks so much did not even know I could do this, import numpy as np.